# New window with style using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I have a peculiar problem..I am trying to open a new window with content and style in that window using angularjs. I am able to open the window using the standard way as below:
`win.document.open();
 win.document.write('FAQsOpening a new window');
 win.document.close();`

Is there a way where I can avoid using this and use just angular router to embed css in the html. Please advise. I do not like using `document.write`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yup you definitely can

Create a component or directive

```
angular.module('myModule').component('example', {
    template: "<div class='muhClasses'> FAQsOpening a new window</div><div ng-click='$ctrl.click" class="button">click</div>"
    controller: ['$window', function($window){
        this.click = function(){
            console.log('clicked');
            $window.close();
        };
    }]
};
```

Define the state

```
$stateProvider.state('newwindow', {
    url: '/window/',
    component: 'example'
});
```

when you want to open a new window, do

```
var mWindow = $window.open($state.href('newwindow', {}, {absolute: true});
```

this will open a new application window with all the styling used in your application.

after that, you can use the reference to mWindow to get data from it or whatever. Just an example

```
var inputVal = mWindow.angular.element('#input').val();
```

Just a thought, are you sure that you mean to be opening up a new window? Would a [modal](http://likeastore.github.io/ngDialog/#) possibly achieve what you are attempting to?